# How to load seprate css file for each page in Next.js with postcss

Tags: next.js, postcss

I'm trying to use PostCss with next.js which allow me only to add the main css file in the main `_app.js` file, 
which make all the output style global,
how can I create css file for each page or even each component

Answer (score 0):

As of Next.js version 9.2, it supports native css support.

As you said, if you import styles from `_app.js` file, they considered as global styles of your app.

Styles of components are considered "modules".

> CSS Modules locally scope CSS by automatically creating a unique class name. This allows you to use the same CSS class name in different files without worrying about collisions.

All you need to do is call your css files with `*.module.css` suffix.

Check the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css)

Comment: but don't think this will consider working as postcss, this way will not be able to use the power of postcss.

Comment: It has a built-in postcss as well https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/ee9ccc84cc4062e259d4037a2796dba9669a80a6/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config.md